# Create Instance Template based on an exported image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have an image created from a VM and I want to create an Instance Template to use that image for boot disk. I cannot find any way to do this in Google Cloud Console. How can create an Instance Template, using an image for boot disk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Compute Engine -> Images. In Filter images, enter the tag that you used to create the image. If you did not use a tag or something descriptive, then you will have to look thru the entire list. If you do not find your image, then go back and figure out what went wrong with your import.

Once you know your image and its name, go to Compute Engine -> Instance tempates.

Click on `Change` in `Boot disk`. Select the tab `Custom images`. If you do not see your image, then go back again and figure what went wrong with your import.

If you see your image select it and press the `Select` button. Continue configuring your instance template.

Comment: For some reason, the `Custom images` tab was not available, but when I tried from scratch the tab was there. I don't know why.

Comment: I figured when "Deploy a container image to this VM instance." checkbox is checked then we cannot select a custom image. So that was the problem.